# VerifyCsrfToken always called when route to API Middleware Laravel 5.2.35

Tags: laravel, cookies, header, request, csrf

I have two similiar Laravel project. This is part code of kernel.php. Both projects have same code.

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],
    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
];
```

But, VerifyCsrfToken always be called although I put my route inside `api` middlewareGroup.

I check request header in Advanced REST Client. I found this.

First project result :

[image]
[image]

Second project result :

[image]
[image]

First result has cookie attribute in request header, but second result doesn't have

Comment: tough to say without seeing the controller code that is producing these responses.  Refer to https://laravel.com/docs/master/responses

Comment: @Jeff I attached Request screenshot instead of Response screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the routes in `routes.php` are included in a route group which has the 'web' middleware applied. You should probably create another routes file and have the RouteServiceProvider load those in a group with 'api' and without the 'web' middleware applied.

If you open up your RouteServiceProvider you will see where this is happening. Check the `map` method to see it calling `mapWebRoutes`.

Comment: I don't know my first `RouteServiceProvider.php` and second `RouteServiceProvider.php` has different code

Answer (score 1):

You can skip csrf token check for all your api links in `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` by adding the URIs to the $except property. Example:

```
protected $except = [
    '/api/*'
];
```

Comment: Your answer is true. But I am curious about everything. Because everything is similar. The second project doesn't have exception variable, but it can except csrftoken.

Comment: Both projects has same SESSION_DRIVER value in your .env file? Check your session settings, possibly you store it in file, but forget to set permissions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use routes without any middleware and it will not require csrf token anymore.